# How to divide two elements of list using python

Tags: python

I have python code as follow.
jv_list is populated from resultset retrieve from D.B. query.

```
jv_list = list(result.get_points())
print(jv_list)
```

I am printing jv_list and it is giving me below mention output.

```
[{u'in': u'19834', u'length-bytes': u'79923888', u'run-time': u'1h50m43.489993955s', u'time': u'2017-09-08T21:20:39.846582783Z'}]
```

How can i get division result which is actually second value divided by first value. for. `i.e. 79923888/ 19834`

Comment: You want the result of `length-bytes / in`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you mean

```
x = [{u'in': u'19834', u'length-bytes': u'79923888', u'run-time': u'1h50m43.489993955s', u'time': u'2017-09-08T21:20:39.846582783Z'}]
for i in x:
    print(float(i['length-bytes'])/float(i['in']))
```

results as

```
4029.64041544822
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this sequence of commands

```
>>> X = [{u'in': u'19834', u'length-bytes': u'79923888', u'run-time': u'1h50m43.489993955s', u'time': u'2017-09-08T21:20:39.846582783Z'}]
>>> for x in X:
...     x['answer'] = float(x['length-bytes'])/float(x['in'])
...
>>> X
[{'in': '19834', 'length-bytes': '79923888', 'run-time': '1h50m43.489993955s', 'time': '2017-09-08T21:20:39.846582783Z', 'answer': 4029.64041544822}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably do that, dictionaries are unordered.
With this data structure, you will need to address the elements via their keys.

that is `jv_list[0]['length_bytes'] / jv_list[0]['in']` for each pair of elements you want to divide by each other.

Comment: Assuming if query return one row only?

Comment: If one row only, you still need to address the elements by key.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result of `length-bytes / in`, you can use those keys and retrieve their values:

```
jv_list = [{u'in': u'19834', u'length-bytes': u'79923888', u'run-time': u'1h50m43.489993955s', u'time': u'2017-09-08T21:20:39.846582783Z'}]

result = float(jv_list[0]['length-bytes']) / float(jv_list[0]['in'])
print(result) # => 4029.64041544822
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data structure it seems this would be the answer.

```
float(jv_list[0]['length-bytes']) / float(jv_list[0]['in'])
```